# Titanium: Youtube video

Tags: iphone, mobile, youtube, titanium

How can I show a youtube or bits on the run video full screen on my app? Is there a special link I have to naviate to? Or is there a special API that takes care of that to view it fullscreen?

The idea is to click on a link 'show video', then show the video fullscreen, and get a button play pauze and 'done'. When clicked done it goes back to the previous page.

I don't know how to get started on this one. Can anyone help me out?

I'm creating an iPhone app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Muhammad has the first part right but to get it to close when you hit the blue done button you'll need the following code.

replace

```
win.add(activeMovie);
activeMovie.play();
```

with

```
win.add(activeMovie);
activeMovie.fullscreen = 1; // this must be defined after you add to the window!
activeMovie.play();
```

then add this

```
activeMovie.addEventListener('fullscreen', function(e) {
    if(!e.entering) { // this is run only when exiting fullscreen aka the blue done button
        activeMovie.stop();
    }
});
```

Comment: I know this but some thing must be left to do for Tjekkles... :)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I already had this code, but when I put a youtube link in there the player just keeps on loading, but it doesn't do that with the apple link. You happen to know why this is? I used this link: youtube.com/watch?v=fRrU2RFX3_U

Comment: Well, i guess it's because it's not a direct link to the video itself? Is there any way I can get that link if thats the reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a an example code to show video with controlls

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
    var contentURL = 'http://movies.apple.com/media/us/ipad/2010/tours/apple-ipad-video-us-20100127_r848-9cie.mov';

    var activeMovie = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
        contentURL: contentURL,
        backgroundColor:'#111',
        movieControlMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT,
        scalingMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_FILL
    });

 win.add(activeMovie);
 activeMovie.play();
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I already had this code, but when I put a youtube link in there the player just keeps on loading, but it doesn't do that with the apple link. You happen to know why this is? I used this link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRrU2RFX3_U

Comment: Well, i guess it's because it's not a direct link to the video itself? Is there any way I can get that link if thats the reason? Thanks!

Comment: That's not YouTube. It's a mov file from Apple.com.